# C union assignment with big endian

Tags: c, endianness, unions

```c
#include <stdio.h>

union data{
    int n;
    char ch;
    short m;
};

int main(){
    union data a;
    printf("%d, %d\\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(union data) );
    a.n = 0x40;
    printf("%X, %c, %hX\\n", a.n, a.ch, a.m);
    a.ch = '9';
    printf("%X, %c, %hX\\n", a.n, a.ch, a.m);
    return 0;
}
```

My computer is little endian,so the answer is:

```
4, 4
40, @, 40
39, 9, 39
```

But if the machine is big endian,
when `a.n=0x40`,the `a` from the lowest to the highest will be 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40,

when `a.ch='9'`,will the whole 4 bytes be overwrited or just cover the lowest byte and become 0x39 0x00 0x00 0x40?

Comment: `a.ch` is 1 byte, and writing to it writes just the one byte (the byte at the lowest address, regardless of endianness).

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 6.2.6.1 7 says:

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

Some points:

- A C implementation could choose to always assign all bytes of the union.
- A C implementation could choose to always assign only the bytes of the member assigned and to leave the others unchanged.
- A C implementation may do different things in different circumstances. For example, if there is an isolated assignment, the compiler might just write the byte(s) of the assigned member to memory. But, if there is an assignment mixed with other uses, and the compiler has bytes from the previously assigned member already in a register, the compiler might optimize the assignment to a register load or copy that changes the whole register and then later write the register to memory, thus overwriting the whole union instead of just the byte(s) of the newly assigned member.
- In the definition of the C standard, an “unspecified value” is not actually a value at all; it is a sort of amorphous state in which the bytes may have different values each time they are used. This means, once you have assigned a smaller member, the implementation does not actually have to use the other bytes in memory when you attempt to use a different member—it can use whatever bytes are handy, such as whatever is lying in a processor register.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard, when a union member is written, all bytes of the union that do not correspond to that member's representation take unspecified values. (C17 6.2.6.1/6-7)

It is possible that those unspecified values can be read back as the same values those locations previously held, but a strictly conforming program cannot rely on that to be the case.

In practice, you might plausibly find (for example) a compiler to implement some or all writes to the example union as four-byte writes from a register to memory, so that indeed, assigning a value to `a.ch` modifies more than one byte of `a.n` and `a.m`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a.n=0x11223344, this way you can see if the compiler will overwrite the total structure or just a part of it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. It might show or not show behaviour in a specific case, but doesn't guarantee that it'll always be that way. See the other answer.

Comment: The other answer say it is unspecified what will happen. The question was: will the whole 4 bytes be overwrited or just cover the lowest byte and become 0x39 0x00 0x00 0x40? Did the other answers answered this? I think Rongxuan was just curious.

Comment: That's the point. You can't be sure what will happen, it's some unspecified value. It could be preserved, it could be cleared, the compiler could fill the spare space with a poem about the beauty of a sunset.